# Accept data from the console

Tags: assembly, x86-16, masm

How to write loops / arrays that repeat the entered string ?

I want to achieve re-display in the environment after typing the string

it wants the program to accept data from the console and display it directly

```
napis db "Wprowadz napis",13,10,'$' - enter the "inscription"
bufor db 20,0,20 dup ('$')
.code
start:
       ;przyg. segmentowej cz. adresu
       mov ax, seg _data
       mov ds, ax

       ;przyg. offsetowej cz. adresu
       mov dx, offset napis
       mov di, dx
       ;wyswietlenie znakow
       mov cx, 10h
       mov ah, 02h
drukuj: - print 
       mov dl,ds:[di]
       int 21h
       inc di
       dec cx
jnz drukuj 

       ;wczytanie znakow - loading characters
       mov dx, offset bufor
       mov di, dx
       mov ah, 01h
wpisuj: - enter:
       int 21h
       mov ds:[di], al
       inc di
       cmp al, 13 ;czy enter?
jnz wpisuj 

       mov ax,4c00h
       int 21h
end start
```

Comment: This makes no sense: *In order to do what you want to do - what could be the second time the first viewer, you just need to put in " ?*

Comment: it's okay now ?

Comment: After each letter or after enter? For both there are DOS API calls IIRC. http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html

Comment: I mean, I don't know what you're talking about, I mean adding a loop that causes it to repeat i wanna only

Comment: u know what do u mean

Comment: You want to display the entered data (again) - that could be done after each keypress or after each line